A Conjecture Involving Odd Primes Ending in $1$
Context and Motivation
Consider the function:
$$
f(n)= (a^n + a^{-n})(b^n + b^{-n})
,$$
where,
\begin{align*}
a & =\tan{9^\circ}=\tan{\pi/20}=1+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}=\varphi^{-1}(2+\sqrt{2^2 - \varphi^{-2}})^{-1} \\
b & =\tan{27^\circ}=\tan{3\pi/20}=-1+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}=\varphi(2+\sqrt{2^2 - \varphi^2})\\
\varphi & =\text{Golden Ratio}.
\end{align*}
The function $f(n)$ arises from trigonometric expressions involving $\tan9^\circ$ and $\tan27^\circ$, which are notable due to their connections to geometric constructs and special angles in number theory. Its recursive and multiplicative structure makes it intriguing to study its prime factors.
This conjecture builds on computational observations suggesting a peculiar property: all odd prime factors of $f(n)$ consistently end with the digit 1. Such patterns are rare and often indicate deep mathematical phenomena related to modular arithmetic or cyclotomic fields. Verifying or proving this conjecture could uncover new insights into the properties of prime numbers and their distributions.
Primes ending in $1$ are a subset of primes, and their persistent appearance in $f(n)$ points to an underlying algebraic or geometric symmetry.
The Conjecture

Every odd prime factor of $f(n)$ ends with the digit $1$, where $n$ is
any integer.

We would never see a prime ending in $3, 7$, or $9$ in the prime factorization of $f(n)$.
$f(0)$ and $f(\pm1)$ do not show any odd prime factors.
Supporting Evidence
Here are some computed examples:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(0) & = 2^2 \\
f(\pm 1) & = 2^4 \\
f(\pm 2) & = 2^2 \times 41 \\
f(\pm 3) & = 2^4 \times 11^2 \\
f(\pm 4) & = 2^2 \times 31 \times 191 \\
f(\pm 5) & = 2^4 \times 101 \times 181 \\
f(\pm 6) & = 2^2 \times 41 \times 71 \times 311 \\
f(\pm 7) & = 2^4 \times 251 \times 11171 \\
f(\pm 8) & = 2^2 \times 31 \times 4482911 \\
f(\pm 9) & = 2^4 \times 11^2 \times 71 \times 50111 \\
f(\pm 10) & = 2^2 \times 41^2 \times 601 \times 21121 \\
f(\pm 11) & = 2^4 \times 131 \times 14741 \times 34231 \\
f(\pm 12) & = 2^2 \times 31 \times 191 \times 241 \times 2296081 \\
f(\pm 13) & = 2^4 \times 311 \times 521 \times 3121 \times 20071 \\
f(\pm 14) & = 2^2 \times 41 \times 12270397265281 \\
f(\pm 15) & = 2^4 \times 11^2 \times 101 \times 181 \times 19441 \times 36241 \\
f(\pm 16) & = 2^2 \times 77247723156574721 \\
f(\pm 17) & = 2^4 \times 1021 \times 1291 \times 181549608511 \\
f(\pm 18) & = 2^2 \times 41 \times 71 \times 311 \times 6481 \times 2021549041 \\
f(\pm 19) & = 2^4 \times 36744345067538002201 \\
f(\pm 20) & = 2^2 \times 31 \times 191 \times 4241 \times 4721 \times 116881 \times 131441 \\
f(\pm 21) & = 2^4 \times 11^2 \times 251 \times 11171 \times 379931 \times 43770131 \\
f(\pm 22) & = 2^2 \times 41 \times 1231 \times 233551121 \times 23724193151. \\
\end{align*}
$$
In each case, we observe that all odd prime factors of $f(n)$ consistently end with $1$.
Here are some additional observations:
\begin{align*}
f(p)/16 & \equiv 1 \pmod{p}, && \text{for any odd prime } p. \\
f(2mn+n) & \equiv 0 \pmod{f(n)}, && \text{for any whole number } m.
\end{align*}
We also see a cyclical pattern in the tangent function, which hints at a potential periodic structure in $f(n)$:
$$\tan f(7.5 \pm m + 30n)^\circ = \tan \theta$$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
m & \theta \\ \hline
0.5 & \mp76^\circ \\
1.5 & \mp44^\circ \\ \hline
2.5 & \pm4^\circ \\
3.5 & \pm76^\circ \\ \hline
4.5 & \pm44^\circ \\
5.5 & \pm16^\circ \\ \hline
6.5 & \mp16^\circ \\
7.5 & \mp 4^\circ \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
For example,
\begin{align*}
\tan{f(\pm 17)^\circ} & = \tan{f(7.5 + 5.5 - 30 \times 1)^\circ} = \tan{16^\circ}, \\
\tan{f(\pm 123)^\circ} & = \tan{f(7.5 - 4.5 + 30 \times 4)^\circ} = -\tan{44^\circ}. \\
\end{align*}
Also,
\begin{align*}
(a^{3} + a^{-3})(b^{3} + b^{-3}) & = (a^2 + a^{-2} + b^2 + b^{-2})^2 = 1936 = 44^2, \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} & = (ab)^{-1}, \\
\text{Let } x & = (ab)^{-1} - \lfloor (ab)^{-1}\rfloor,\\
\lfloor\arccos(x) + \arctan(x)\rfloor - \lfloor\arccos(x)\rfloor & = \lfloor\arccos(x)\rfloor - \lfloor\arcsin(x) + \arctan(x)\rfloor = \textbf{22}, \\
\lfloor\arcsin(x) + \arctan(x)\rfloor & = a^2 + a^{-2} + b^2 + b^{-2} = \textbf{44}, \\
\lfloor\arccos(x) + \arctan(x)\rfloor & = \textbf{88}, \\
\lfloor\arccos(x)\rfloor & = \textbf{66}.
\end{align*}
Request
The conjecture presents a curious interplay between trigonometry, number theory, and prime factorization.
Can anyone provide a proof or insights into why every odd prime factor of $f(n)$ ends with the digit 1?
Suggestions on the additional observations are also welcome!

Since the odd factors are (trivially) already $1\bmod2$, the question is really about why the odd prime factors are $\equiv 1\bmod5$. Given that the quantities at play involve $\sqrt{5}$ it doesn't seem entirely out of reason, though ten examples is a very small number. How far out have you computed factorizations?

Upto 108, beyond which the computational time was too long. I believe the conjecture is always true.

Why was this question closed? Sounds like an interesting question (although it could have been more concisely written).

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

For reference, the minimal polynomials of $a$ and $b$ respectively are $x^4-4x^3-14x^2-4x+1$ and $x^4+4x^3-14x^2+4x+1$. Since these polynomials are palindromic, $a^n+a^{-n}$ and $b^n+b^{-n}$ are natural quantities to study. For example, the minimal polynomial of $a+a^{-1}$ is $x^2-4x-16$. Anyway, congruence conditions satisfied by prime divisors smells like a reciprocity law to me.

$a^{\pm 1}=x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}; b^{\pm }=y \pm \sqrt{y^2-1}, x,y=\sqrt{5} \pm 1$. Then $f(n)=\sum_{p} a_p x^p$ where $n \equiv p (mod 2)$. Here, $a_{n-2l}=(-1)^l\sum \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}$. This implies that we need to find $\sum a_p^2$ or $\sum a_pa_{p-2}$ modulo $5$. It also explains why $2^2, 2^4$ divide $f(n)$ for even and odd $n$ respectively.

Does $f$ satisfy a linear recurrence?

I'm always puzzled when a question refers specifically to the decimal expansion but never says it explicitly.

@DanielWeber $f(n)=u_nv_n$ where $u_n=2xu_{n-1}-u_{n-2}$ and $v_n=2yv_{n-1}-v_{n-2}$ where $x,y=\sqrt{5}\pm 1$, if this helps.

So is this quadratic reciprocity over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$, followed by taking norms to $\mathbb{Q}$?

$f$ satisfies the linear recurrence $f(n) = 16f(n-1) - 46f(n-2) + 16f(n-3) - f(n-4)$

@DanielWeber : using you recursion I checked that the result holds for all primes $<200000$. I used a simple awk line (after defining an isprime() function). Is there some trick that could speed up a similar check?   gawk 'BEGIN {for(p=3; p<=200000; p+=2) if(isprime(p) && p%10!=1) {a=0; b=4%p; c=16%p; d=441%p; e=16121%p; for(i=1; i<=p; i++) {a=b; b=c; c=d; d=e; e=(16d-46c+16*b-a)%p; if(e==0) {print i, p; exit;}}}}'

@YaakovBaruch Why does doing $p$ iterations suffice? Isn't it possible that you'd need up to $p^4$?

@DanielWeber : I was thinking after $p$ iterations one falls into periodicity, but you are 100% correct and, barring deeper insights, $p^4$ are needed. Which means that (as far as I got now) the conjecture is true for $p=83$. It may pay off at this point to rewrite the inner loop in a way that keeps track of past quadruples through a hash table.

The answer is yes. The proof, given in (too much) detail below, uses basic properties of prime ideals and Frobenius elements as can be seen in a first course in algebraic number theory.
Let $L = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $20$th root of unity, it is a degree $8$ totally complex abelian extension. Then
$$K = \mathbf{Q}(a) = \mathbf{Q}(b) \subset L.$$
This follows most naturally from the description of the tangent function at rational multiples of $\pi$ in terms of roots of unity. But if you want a totally explicit proof, you can observe, concretely, that if $\zeta = \exp(2 \pi i/20)$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
a & = 
2 - 2 \zeta + 2 \zeta^4 - \zeta^5 - 2 \zeta^6 + 2 \zeta^7, \\
b & =  -2 \zeta + 2 \zeta^3 + 2 \zeta^4 - \zeta^5 - 2 \zeta^6.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence both $a$ and $b$ live in the unique totally real subfield $K$ of $L$ of degree $4$. They have minimal polynomials
$$x^4-4x^3-14x^2 - 4x+1=0,$$
$$x^4+4x^3-14x^2 + 4x+1=0.$$
($b$ is a Galois conjugate of $-a$). From these polynomials, it follows that not only are $a$ and $b$ algebraic integers, they are algebraic units.
There are canonical isomorphisms
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbf{Q}) & = (\mathbf{Z}/20 \mathbf{Z})^{\times}, \\
\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q}) & = (\mathbf{Z}/20 \mathbf{Z})^{\times}/\{\pm 1\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
The second group is cyclic of order four; let $\sigma$ be a generator.
Moreover, one also sees that
$$\sigma^2 a = a^{-1}; \quad \sigma^2 b = b^{-1}.$$
This is because $a^{-1}$ is a conjugate of $a$,
and $\sigma$ acts transitively on the four conjugates and has order $4$. The same argument applies to $b$.
Let's return to the original problem. I'll leave it to the reader to see what happens when $p=2$ or $p=5$.
If your expression is divisible by a prime $p$, then $a^n + a^{-n}$
or $b^n + b^{-n}$ is divisible by a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ above $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$.
The argument in either case is the same so WLOG let's consider the case of $a$.
We find that (using that $a$ is a unit) that
$$a^{2n} \equiv -1 \bmod \mathfrak{p}.$$
In particular,
$$a^n \equiv i \bmod \mathfrak{p},$$
where $i \in \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ is an element of square $-1$.
Since $p \ne 2,5$, the prime $p$
is unramified in $L$ and thus $K$. Let's consider various cases. Let $N(\mathfrak{p})$ denote the norm of $\mathfrak{p}$.

$N(\mathfrak{p}) = p^4$. In this case $\mathrm{Frob}_p$ has order $4$, and so $\mathrm{Frob}^2_p = \sigma^2$. Moreover, the Galois automorphism $\sigma$ preserves the ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.
Now $\mathbf{F}_p(i) \subset \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ has
degree at most $2$ since $i^2+1=0$, so $i$ must be fixed by the square of Frobenius. But now applying $\sigma^2 = \mathrm{Frob}^2_p$ to both sides, we get

$$\begin{aligned}
\sigma^2 a^{n}  & \equiv \sigma^2 i \bmod \mathfrak{p}, \\
a^{-n} & \equiv \mathrm{Frob}^2_p i \bmod \mathfrak{p}, \\
i^{-1} & \equiv i \bmod \mathfrak{p},
\end{aligned}$$
but this is a contradiction since it implies that $i^2 \equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak{p}$ and $p \ne 2$.

$N(\mathfrak{p}) = p^2$, and $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. In this case $\mathrm{Frob}_p$ has order $2$ and so equals $\sigma^2$, and this
preserves the ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.
By assumption, $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and so $i \in \mathbf{F}_p$ is fixed by Frobenius.
Thus, applying $\sigma^2$ to both sides, we get

$$\begin{aligned}
\sigma^2 a^{n}  & \equiv \sigma^2 i \bmod \mathfrak{p}, \\
a^{-n} & \equiv \mathrm{Frob}_p i \bmod \mathfrak{p}, \\
i^{-1} & \equiv i \bmod \mathfrak{p},
\end{aligned}$$
and we get a contradiction exactly above.

$N(\mathfrak{p}) = p$, and $p \equiv -1 \bmod 4$.
In this case we have

$$a^n \equiv i \bmod \mathfrak{p},$$
but $N(\mathfrak{p}) = p$ implies that the residue field is $\mathbf{F}_p$, and $i \in \mathbf{F}_p$ only when $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, contradicting the fact that $p \equiv -1 \bmod 4$.
Now we know that Frobenius in $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q})$
is just
$$[p] \in (\mathbf{Z}/20 \mathbf{Z})^{\times}/\{\pm 1\},$$
because Frobenius in $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbf{Q})$
sends $\zeta$ to $\zeta^p$ and so is just $[p]$. Thus:

If $p \equiv \pm 3,\pm 7 \bmod 20$ then $\mathfrak{p}$ has norm $p^4$,
and these cases are ruled out by part 1.

If $p \equiv \pm 9 \bmod 20$ then $\mathfrak{p}$ has norm $p^2$,
and we rule out the case $p \equiv 9 \bmod 20$ which is $1 \bmod 4$ by part 2.

If $p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 20$ then $\mathfrak{p}$ has norm $p$,
and we rule out the case $p \equiv -1 \bmod 20$ which is $-1 \bmod 4$ by part 3.


This leaves $p \equiv 1,11 \bmod 20$ as the only possibilities. Note that from the data both such primes can occur.

Using $\mathcal O_K/(p)$ shows $f(p)\equiv 16\bmod p$ when $p$ is prime: it has characteristic $p$, so $f(p) = (a^p+a^{-p})(b^p+b^{-p}) \equiv (a+a^{-1})^p(b+b^{-1})^p \equiv f(1)^p \bmod p\mathcal O_K$. Since $f(1) = 16$ and $16^p \equiv 16\bmod p\mathbf Z$, we have $f(p) \equiv 16 \bmod p\mathcal O_K$, so $f(p) \equiv 16\bmod p\mathbf Z$ since $\mathcal O_K\cap \mathbf Q  = \mathbf Z$.

So, does this answer completely prove that why every odd prime factor of $f(n)$ ends with the digit $1$? If yes, then can we promote the conjecture to a theorem?

@DevSharma Yes. The fact that $p=5$ does not occur among the prime divisors follows from Alapan Das's post, while the prime factors $p\neq 5$ were treated in this response. You should accept it as the official answer.

@GHfromMO, Can you suggest a name to this new theorem (previously a conjecture)?

@DevSharma Most theorems don't get a name, because they are not that important. If a professional mathematician gets a named theorem in their lifetime, they can feel lucky. So leave this to the community, and wait a few decades.

Is any other linearly recursive sequence, that avoids all primes in a certain congruence class, known? If so, what would be the simplest such (i.e. lowest degree)?

@YaakovBaruch That could be a separate MathOverflow question in its own right.

All prime factors of $a_n = 4^n + 1$ are $1 \bmod 4$. All prime factors of $a_n = 4^n$ are $2 \bmod 4$.

Ah, of course! Thank you.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers

Thanks for writing this up nicely! I think one of the important and underrated uses of MO is leaving a record of well written solutions, so that someone who is new to a field can read through them and see how problems are solved.

Proof of appearance of $1$ in the odd part as a whole:
The given function $f(n)=A_nB_n=(a^n+a^{-n})(b^{n}+b^{-n})$ where $a^{\pm 1}=x\pm \sqrt{x^2-1}, b^{\pm 1}=y\pm \sqrt{y^2-1}$ and $x,y=\sqrt{5}\pm 1$. Or,
$$A_n=2\sum_{k=0} \binom{n}{2k} x^{n-2k}(x^2-1)^k=2\sum_{p} a_px^{p}$$ where $n\equiv_2 p$ and
$$a_{n-2l}=(-1)^l\sum_{k=l}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}\binom{k}{l}.$$
Hence,
$$4^{-1}.f(n)=\sum_{q} 4^q\biggl[a_q^2+\sum_{d=1}a_qa_{q+2d} (x^{2d}+y^{2d})\biggr]$$
as $xy=4$. Now, $(x^{2d}+y^{2d})\equiv_5 2$ or $\equiv_2 0$. When $n$ is even, $a_0=1$ and for odd $n$, $a_1^2=4n^2$ giving the $2^2$ factor.
Now, $4^q\equiv_5 (-1)^n$ gives
$$4^{-1}f(n) \equiv_5 (-1)^n\biggl(\sum_p a_p\biggr)^2.$$
But,
$$\sum_p a_p=\sum_{k \geq 0}\binom{n}{2k} \biggl(\sum_l \binom{k}{l} (-1)^l\biggr)=1.$$
So, $4^{-1}f(n) \equiv_5 (-1)^n$. But, $f/4$ has a factor $2^0$ and $2^2\equiv_50$ which implies that the odd part is $\equiv_5 1$. This proves the origin of $1$ in the odd part.
P.S. Here, $\equiv_m$ means modulo $m$.

Why is this a partial answer?

@Dev Sharma, sorry, for the confusion. This is just the proof of appearance of $1$ in the odd part. Will change it. I meant partial in that sense.

Now that Daniel Weber produced the recursive formula, the 2-period pattern $4(10m+1), 16(10n+1)$ is more easily proved from that.

@YaakovBaruch yes, I noticed that later. But thanks for mentioning.

So, Is a complete proof not possible?

@DevSharma . A modular result, as in this answer, is a standard consequence of a recurrence. What you are wondering about is much deeper and if it weren't for the intruiguing trigonometric source of the recurrence, I would be inclined to think that the conjecture is false and it just so happens that the particular recursion + law of small numbers push a counter example way out - but in this case Timothy Chow's comment makes the most sense to me.

This is really a comment rather than an answer but it is too long for a comment. I want to explain my remark about smelling like a reciprocity law.
Here's how I want to prove the claim, although it doesn't quite work.
Following the notation of Alapan Das, let
$$\eqalign{A_n &:= a^n + a^{-n}\cr B_n &:= b^n + b^{-n}\cr}$$
Then one can show that
$$\eqalign{A_n &= r_n \sqrt{5} + s_n \cr B_n &= (r_n \sqrt{5} - s_n)(-1)^{n-1}\cr}$$
for some integers $r_n$ and $s_n$ satisfying the recurrences
$$\eqalign{r_n &= 2r_{n-1} + 2s_{n-1} - r_{n-2} \cr
           s_n &= 10r_{n-1} + 2s_{n-1} - s_{n-2} \cr}$$
for $n\ge 3$. Therefore,
$$A_nB_n = (-1)^{n-1}(5r_n^2 - s_n^2).$$
Now suppose that $p$ is an odd prime dividing $A_nB_n$. Then $5r_n^2 = s_n^2 \pmod p$. I would then like to argue that $5 \equiv (s_n/r_n)^2 \pmod p$, so $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. Then by quadratic reciprocity, $p$ is a quadratic residue modulo $5$.
There are two problems with this argument. The first is that in order to divide by $r_n^2 \bmod p$ we have to show that $p\nmid r_n$, and I'm not sure how to prove that. The second problem is that even if we could carry out the argument as I've sketched it, it would only show that $p \equiv \pm 1\pmod 5$ and our goal is to show that $p\equiv 1 \pmod 5$. Still, maybe these comments will help someone construct an actual proof.
